# Which Flash SWF compiler uses compiler directives?

Tags: actionscript, compiler-construction, flash, haxe, mtasc

Any existing Flash SWF compilers that can **understand directives like #IF #ENDIF**, etc?

**Some SWF Compilers:** (Hopefuls)

- AS3 Compiler - [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)
- AS2 Compiler - [MTASC](http://www.mtasc.org/)
- Adobe Flex Compiler - [Mxmlc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/15/flex_docs_en/00000860.htm)
- C# to SWF Compiler - [Debreuil](http://blog.debreuil.com/archive/2004/08/18/376.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `mtasc`, and it does not support this kind of conditional compilation.  However, it looks like Flex 3's `mxmlc` [has support for this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html) via the `-define` command line option.  Also, Haxe [does exactly what you want](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-condition-compilation.html).

Answer (score 1):

The MXMLC compiler also supports conditional compilation, though it is pretty primitive and strangely-implemented.

They didn't implement 'ifdef'. Instead we just get the value after the comma from the assignment. While this works fine for string insertion, it's pretty confusing for booleans.

The following example would only compile the 'release' implementation of the method:

```
-define=CONFIG::debugging,false -define=CONFIG::release,true
```

Then in your source code:

```
CONFIG::debugging
private function configure():void {
    // set up for debugging
}

CONFIG::release
private function configure():void {
    // set up for release
}
```